# Changing lock mechanisms on doors of Jeep Wrangler

Tags: jeep, locks, door, wrangler

Due to a mistake on the build order for my 2017 Jeep Wrangler, I ended up with two sets of doors: one full and one half. As I’m not super excited about having to store one set in my apartment at any given time, I’m contemplating selling the set of full doors.

I presume a buyer would need to swap out the lock mechanism in each door with ones keyed to their existing key or a new key entirely. My concern is that this will make the doors difficult to sell. Is this correct, or is there a way, perhaps at a dealership, to simply re-key the existing door locks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick check on Amazon shows a lockset for less than $15. If they were my doors, I would replace the cylinders. Show the buyer the paperwork for the new cylinders and give them the new keys. Then the buyer has the option of rekeying to match or not. I would have concerns with selling the doors with your original locks installed. They buyer could possibly have keys cut to fit the locks and have access to your vehicle.

Comment: +1 for suggesting to replace the cylinders myself. Didn’t think about a buyer potentially being able to replicate my key.